# Eclipse truncates my compiler problem descriptions

Tags: gcc, makefile, eclipse-cdt, arm-none-eabi-gcc

For a while now, my Eclipse makefile project has been truncating all compiler problem descriptions, both in the code space and in the "Problems" window.
Examples in images below - does anyone know what might cause this please?

[image: Error truncated in code]

[image: Descriptions truncated in "Problems" pane]

I've searched the preferences for a maximum length setting to no avail.

EDIT - UPDATE:

I've installed the latest eclipse CDT and opened the project there. The descriptions are still truncated:

[image: Code space]

[image: Problem window]

Versions tried:

- Microchip SoftConsole v2021.1-6.6.0.507
- Eclipse IDE for C/C++
  Developers (includes Incubating components) Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)

Could this be a compiler issue perhaps? Truncating error messages seems like a redundant control to build in on purpose.

Comment: That looks like a quite old Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers. Can this be reproduced in the current Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Apologies - I was hoping it might be a generic question on eclipse, since I'm using a manufacturer's packaged version:  Microchip SoftConsole v2021.1-6.6.0.507

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it was an issue with an `-fmessage-length` compiler option I was setting in my makefile:

```
# format error messages to output on lines of #num chars
CFLAGS+= -fmessage-length=80
```

Removing the option has resolved my issue.

---

I had added the `fmessage-length=80` option in order to format command line outputs so that they'd appear like this:

[image]

However in Eclipse this causes the compiler warnings to be truncated, like this:
[image]